# How to get true positive, true negative, and false positive false negative rate correctly using Keras?

Tags: classification, keras, tensorflow

I'm using Keras to do binary classification, and the label was encoded using one-hot encoding. I tried to get the number of True Positives, True Negatives and false positives and false negatives using

```
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
              # optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = lr_schedule),
              optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = lr_schedule),
              metrics = [
                         tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(),
                         tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives(),
                         tf.keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(),
                         tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(),
                         tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives()
                         ]
              )
```

but the results seems wrong:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 408us/step - loss: 0.2671 - binary_accuracy: 0.8800 - true_positives: 22.0000 - true_negatives: 22.0000 - false_positives: 3.0000 - false_negatives: 3.0000
    Epoch 12/20
    1/1 [==============================] - 0s 419us/step - loss: 0.2206 - binary_accuracy: 0.9200 - true_positives: 23.0000 - true_negatives: 23.0000 - false_positives: 2.0000 - false_negatives: 2.0000
    Epoch 13/20
    1/1 [==============================] - 0s 410us/step - loss: 0.2280 - binary_accuracy: 0.8800 - true_positives: 22.0000 - true_negatives: 22.0000 - false_positives: 3.0000 - false_negatives: 3.0000
```

The number of `true_positives` and `true_negatives` got exactly the same value, `false_positives` and `false_negatives` got the same value. There are 25 training samples.
My questions are:

1. Why is this wrong?
2. How to access the number of `true_positives` and `true_negatives`  `false_positives` and `false_negatives` correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `loss: 1.1836 - binary_accuracy: 0.7500 - true_positives: 9.0000 - true_negatives: 9.0000 - false_positives: 3.0000 - false_negatives: 3.0000`, this is what I got after training, and since there are only 12 samples in the test, it is not possible that there are 9 true positive and 9 true negative

Comment: If would help if you could provide predicted and expected labels for this particular situation. Otherwise it is a bit of tasseography rather than computer science.

Comment: You probably have a confusion about which part of the data is evaluated: the results you gave in the question show 50 instances, the ones in the comment show 24. Every time it's twice the number you mention, but since we don't know your data it's hard to know what happens.